# ViewPager with no snapping

Tags: android, android-viewpager

**What I would like to achieve:** Have a ViewPager with TabLayout where each Tab contains a new Fragment that has a RecyclerView layout out horizontally and managed by a FragmentPagerAdapter.

**What I am struggling with:** The default behaviour is that when you get end of the list on one of the tabs, it switches Tabs and snaps (snapping means if you pull over 50% of the viewport, it jumps to either direction). I want it to free-flow and not to snap. Sort of like how it happens in iOS by default.

I got inspired for this setup by the following two CodePath guide:

- https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout
- https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

How should I approach this problem (preferably without any other libraries)?

Comment: So it sounds like you don't want the swipe-to-change-tabs behavior that is part of `ViewPager`.  Is that correct?  In that case, don't use a `ViewPager` at all, just use the tabs to load the different fragments into a fixed container.

Comment: @krislarson I do want the swipe-to-change-tabs behaviour, i just don't want it to snap automatically but to fluently scroll over, for example as the emoji keyboard works on iOS (i want similar behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of a `ViewPager`. The only caveat is that the view pager sends the lifecycle events to fragments as you scroll between them, whereas for `HorizontalScrollView` you will have to add them initially, and then they will be continuously active unless you manually change that. Also you may have an option to not use the fragments and use simple views depending on what you use the fragments for.

I would definitely *not* override the touch events for the `ViewPager` because it does some cleanup when it detects the `UP` motion, so just swallowing it is not a correct thing to do.

Comment: Well, it started out as a `HorizontalScrollView` with a `RecyclerView` for rendering the items with a `TabLayout`, but we have different size of items per "tab", therefore splitting them up into `Fragment`s are ideal for each of the tabs to have their own `RecyclerView`. That is what drove me to the `ViewPager` approach, but the only roadblock is the snap-effect. Are you saying that is by design and no "nice" and suggested way around it and my only approach is still the `HorizontalScrollView`? Thanks for the initial answer!

Comment: @anthonymonori You don't really need a ViewPager to use the fragments and vice-versa. Unfortunately, you can't disable the snapping in ViewPager judging by its source code, so you'll have to use another widget in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!